# Why do .NET methods sometimes return general types instead of using generics and type constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

Consider, for example, the method:

```
public static Attribute GetCustomAttribute(this ParameterInfo element, Type attributeType);
```

defined in `System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions`

Wouldn't it make more sense to define instead:

```
public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this ParameterInfo element, T attributeType) where T : Attribute;
```

And save the casting?

Comment: You are effectively asking: "Why isn't everything in .Net libraries (such as the BCL) implemented with generics?" But as you can see from the answers and comments they will all get stuck on your single example of Attributes.

Comment: @kjbartel I have other examples : PropertyInfo.GetValue(..) , PropertyInfo.GetType() (how many do you want?). And I'm not asking why isn't everything in .NET implemented with generics, I'm asking why do methods sometimes return base types instead of using generics

Comment: SO isn't a very good site for asking broad general questions. I know there are lots of examples. But people get stuck on the one or two you give and that's it.

Comment: Matias's answer is about the best you'll get: generics didn't exist when a lot of the stuff was written and there are other cases where you don't know the type at compile time so you need a non-generic method. Other than that it comes down to cost-benefit for the .Net team. They can't implement everything so they focus on the important stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a an overload that is equivalent to your example, [`GetCustomAttribute<T>(ParameterInfo)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194315(v=vs.110).aspx), however to call this method without nasty reflection, you need to know the type of T at compile time. If you only know the type of T at run time then the equivalent method is [`GetCustomAttribute(ParameterInfo, Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?#System_Reflection_CustomAttributeExtensions_GetCustomAttribute_System_Reflection_ParameterInfo_System_Type_)

Answer (score 3):

The non-generic method of retrieving custom attribute is from the old .NET days when generics weren't implemented.

For current and future coding, you can take advantage of [`CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194330%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - *if you're coding using .NET 4.5 version and above* -.

Sadly - or maybe *actually* - software has a sequential evolution. I mean, there was a time where generic weren't with us (.NET 1.0 and 1.1), and there's a lot of code base that's inherited from early .NET versions, and because of framework team prioritzation it seems like not every method that would be better using a generic parameter(s) has been already implemented.

### About *inherited code*

@BenRobinson said in some comment here bellow:

> The point I was making was that these extension methods were added in
>   .net 4.5 (all of them not just the generic ones) and extension methods
>   were added after generics so non generic extension methods of any kind
>   have nothing to do with backwards compatibility with .net 1.0/1.1.

I'm adding this to avoid confusion: don't understand *inherited code* in terms of Microsoft not changing the non-generic code base because of backwards compatibility with third-party code.

Actually, I'm pointing out that current .NET version **itself** has a lot of code inherited from early .NET versions, either if the intention of Microsoft is maintaining backwards compatibility with third-party code or not.

I assume or guess that .NET Framework Team has prioritized new base class library (BCL) and satellite frameworks additions and some of members coming from pre-generics era are still *as is* because the change isn't worth the effort, or we could discuss if it's worth the effort and they did design decision mistakes, but StackOverflow isn't a discussion board, is it?

Comment: Extension methods were added in c# 3 after generics were added in c# 2. These particular extension methods were added in .net 4.5.

Comment: @BenRobinson And am I not saying that in my answer? :D I can add the extension methods reference...

Comment: @BenRobinson BTW I believe extension methods have nothing to do with having generic versions of some methods or not :\

Comment: The point I was making was that these extension methods were added in .net 4.5 (all of them not just the generic ones) and extension methods were added after generics so non generic extension methods of any kind have nothing to do with backwards compatibility with .net 1.0/1.1.

Comment: @BenRobinson I'm not telling you "it's because of backwards compatibility with .net 1.x", I'm just telling you that there's a lot of non-generic-based codebase inherited from .NET 1.0/1.1. Because of backward compatibility or not, they've not rewritten that code, who knows why... Well, because this is their prioritization, am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, it just does not seem relevant to this particular case.

Comment: @BenRobinson Anyway, I've updated my answer to answer your concerns :D Maybe it's not 100% relevant, but I was trying to teach the OP about why sometimes we don't find what we want to find in a software product like .NET

Answer (score 0):

Generics was added to the C# language in version 2. I believe that attributes was in the language at version 1 or 1.1 (can't remember which, I think it was in version 1 but I could be wrong).

This means that even though they would have saved a lot of unnecessary casting by changing all methods to use generics instead, they could have broken backwards compatability. And breaking backwards compatability is bad™.

**Edit:**

Also, I just thought about one more reason.
If you are writing reflection code it's often quite a hassle to call a generic method via reflection (C# has a really stupid api for doing so...) so if you are writing reflection code then using the non-generic version is in many cases much easier than using the generic one.

**Edit again:**

Damn, Ben Robinson beat me to the reflection point by a minute! :)

Comment: What? `CustomAttributeExtensions` class is new in .net 4.5. -1

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Read the answer again, it doesn't say anything about custom attribute extensions. `GetCustomAttribute` has been there since 1.1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.getcustomattribute(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Neolisk You go and read the question again. Question is about `CustomAttributeExtensions` and not something else.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel CustomAttributeExtension contains both the generic and the non-generic version. Most likely this is to make it easier to use for backwards compatability purposes since the GetCustomAttribute in v1.1 has been around with a certain api since forever.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yeah, right, sorry. The answer, however, *does* represent valid points that a non-generic version is there because generic themselves weren't yet available in 1.1, it does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: The word *backwards compatability* isn't really making sense in this context because this is new extension method, there is no way it can affect backward compatability. I don't see what's your point about backward compatability in new API ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Backwards compatability still makes sense though. The upgrade path from the v1.1 non-extension-method way of calling it feels "safer" for programmers when the method signature and return values are similiar. Programmers are creatures of habit and when touching old code that works you don't want to be the one that breaks it. It's a silly reason of course, but combined with the use that the non-generic version has when you're writing reflection code it's certainly reason enough to keep it around.

Comment: None of these methods are available in .net 1 or 1.1. They are part of .net 4.5 and extension methods didn't exist until c# 3 /.net 3.5.